# Setting up new iPhone 6 issues and major headaches

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, restore

Old iPhone 5 16Gb all backed up on iCloud. Tried to set up my brand new iPhone 6 but turned out the last (manual) backup attempted on the 5 hadn't fully completed. Reinitiated a new mail backup on my old 5 to iCloud (18 mins), just attempted to set up new 6 using iCloud but get "error connecting to iCloud". Reset new 6, finally logged into my Apple account but showing zero available iCloud backups with which to restore new 6.

Over an hour and I still cannot even use my new 6!  Currently getting out windows laptop to do it all again manually via iTunes. Just feel like taking the 6 back to the shop.

What can I do to ensure a good restore?

Answer (score 1):

iCloud syncing over iPhones of different generations can be tricky. I highly recommend backing up your iPhone 5 directly to your computer (not iCloud) and then syncing that back up file to your new iPhone 6.

Once all the old data is on your iPhone 6 you can then sync it to iCloud through your iPhone 6 (which can be done in the background).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is the exact build on the iPhone 5 and iPhone 6. If the 6 is at a lesser build version than the 5, no backups will be shown by design.

Once you've gotten both devices updated and backed up, If iCloud servers are under increased load and have elevated API errors, you might need to be patient. Once the iPhone 5 gets a good backup, you can try again there.

Using iTunes to make a local backup might be a great plan and way to avoid any congestion between you and the iCloud servers. It would also cut out busy servers if that is causing you slowness.

Anecdotally, my iCloud backups seem about twice as slow in the 48 hours surrounding a launch. Before the launch, a lot of people presumably are making backups. After it, lots of people chose to wipe their devices and run with all the new settings and defaults for a while before restoring the backup.

It's no fun delaying your new purchase - but I can't think of any other things than to a) avoid the cloud b) make lemonade and try the new phone without a backup while you wait for the iPhone 5 to finish a backup.